# Laravel PDO dump strange bug

Tags: laravel, pdo, dump

Can someone explain this bug please with some way?
I am runing this code on laravel project

```php
try {
    $pdo = \DB::getPdo();
    $query=$select . " {$params} " . self::queryGroup() . " {$orderConditional}";
    $res=$pdo->query($query); 
    // $res->execute();
    $count = $res->rowCount();
    dump($count);//If I delete this dump I receive routing error (see a ittle down)
}
catch( PDOException $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

With dump everything all right :)))

P.S.

## Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

## 1/1 ErrorException in RouteCollection.php line 255:

0 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php(242): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(Array)

1 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)

2 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(613): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

3 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(602): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

4 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(591): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

5 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

6 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

7 /home/demofegllc/public_html/app/Http/Middleware/HttpsProtocol.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

8 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

9 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

10 /home/demofegllc/public_html/app/Http/Middleware/InputTrim.php(28): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

11 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): App\Http\Middleware\InputTrim->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

12 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

13 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

14 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

15 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

16 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

17 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

18 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

19 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

20 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

21 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

22 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

23 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

24 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

25 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

26 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

27 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

28 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

29 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))

30 /home/demofegllc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

31 /home/demofegllc/public_html/public/index.php(60): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

32 {main}

Comment: that error isn't directly from that code ... use the stacktrace to find where the error comes from in your code

Comment: Explaine please why with dump no error Explain please technicaly Thanks It is just routing error Why with dump it works

Comment: use the stacktrace to find where the error is actually coming from then you might know why that is the case

Comment: Probably you are missing some relevant code in your question.